# nottagged only works when tagged is set (/search)

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

On the `/search` route, the nottagged parameter doesn't work properly (at least it isn't specially documented to only work at certain times)
For example:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?pagesize=25&body=true&page=1&nottagged=iphone

returns no results unless the `tagged` parameter is set, even if I set the `intitle` parameter without the `tagged` parameter, `nottagged` still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a documentation bug.

It'd be kind of crazy to return all questions **not tagged** say, [test](/questions/tagged/test).  It makes a great deal more sense to get questions *tagged* [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) but not tagged something, for example.

The documentation has been updated (as has the under constrained search error message, which was misleading/incorrect).

Note that for backward's compatibility reasons, `/search` will continue to behave as it has in the past.  Somebody out there is definitely depending on this behavior, based on call logs.

Comment: Ah, ok. It kind of sucks. Someone's depending on nottagged not working like it mentioned in the documentation? Also what about using nottagged and title? (say searching for iOS in the title, but not wanting iPad tags (and iPhone can't be put in tagged, because theres iphone-sdk, iphone-sdk-3.0 etc)